# static methods returning strings

Tags: c++, string, valgrind

I am having some valgrind issues when I write code like this:

```
static std::string function(std::string test)
{
        size_t pos = test.find(',');
        if (pos == test.npos)
        {
            // no comma
            //
            pos = test.length();
        }

        return test.substr(0, pos); //Valgrind is reporting possibly lost bytes here

}
```

Now my question is should I do this instead?

```
static std::string function(std::string test)
{
        size_t pos = test.find(',');
        if (pos == test.npos)
        {
            // no comma
            //
            pos = test.length();
        }
        static std::string temp = test.substr(0, pos);
        return temp;

}
```

I think that having the string `temp` static is sort of important because `function` is static so anything that is returned by `function` should have the same lifetime as the object incapsulating `function`. Or is my analysis flawed?

Thank you

Comment: Why aren't you passing by const reference since you're not modifying anything?

Comment: I could :) do you think its the issue?

Comment: Hmm, it's not clear why the first snippet would give Valgrind problems.  Can you construct a complete test-case that gives you errors?

Comment: And the second snippet is **definitely** not the solution!  It will only work the first time you use it.

Comment: Seems like Valgrind is being too picky. Try declaring `pos` of type `std::string::size_type`, that may satisfy it.

Comment: Your analysis is flawed.  You just made your code non-re-entrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my question is should I do this instead?

No, definitely not. No need to create such a temporary (and espcially not a `static` one, making the function non-reentrant, or in the end only working the first time in your case). *Valgrind* is reporting rubbish here, I guess. Your code looks fine like it is.

> Or is my analysis flawed?

Yes, it is. A `static` class method doesn't have an object associated with it, which could have a distinct lifetime, anyway (it's like a normal non-class function, just that you need to scope it with the class name when calling). Other than that you don't return a reference to any temporary `string` anyway, but a new object copied from `temp`, so there are no lifetime problems to be taken into account here.

Other than that, you might want to consider taking the `test` object by const-reference, since you don't modify nor copy it (could this be related to general misunderstandings about object identity and object value?).

Answer (score 2):

> I am having some valgrind issues

Exactly! That are Valgrind's issues and not your code issue. Valgrind is not always right and, in this case, gives you false alarm. Just ignore it.

> Now my question is should I do this instead?

No. Static function and static variable are two different things. Also, the second version of code introduces possible issues in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I did not think of that :) indeed I am working in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: I'm not sure "just ignore it" is the first course of action.  There's a real chance that there's a problem elsewhere in the code.  It it really is a false alarm caused by the underlying library doing something weird, then a suppression file would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I reckon Valgrind being not happy due to some static data initialized once and never touched again, or copy-on-write protection. I thought it should be in their suppression list already, perhaps not. There is nothing wrong with the shown piece of code anyway.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I agree there's nothing wrong with the above code.  But there may be something in the surrounding code that's triggering Valgrind here.  I've asked that the OP give us a complete test-case.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that, you will lose thread safety. The first function is good, no memory leaked. You create a `std::string` temporary, but that's OK, no need to worry, it handles the allocated memory perfectly. You have to read the valgrind warning to the letter: I'ts a *warning*, and *valgrind* thinks it's *possibly* lost bytes. Now *you* can go and assure yourself that nothing's lost. 
IIRC there are possibilities to tell valgrind that this time everything is OK.

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet is fine; the second snippet is definitely not fine (it's only guaranteed to work properly the first time you use it).

Everyone else seems to be telling you to ignore Valgrind; **do not do that**.  You haven't shown us the rest of your code, it's quite possible there's a problem elsewhere that's only manifesting itself here.

The second alternative is that your C++ library is doing something wacky which is triggering Valgrind unnecessarily.  If so, then the solution is to use a [*suppression file*](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress).  But you should only do that if you're **100%** sure that it's a library issue; otherwise you will be setting yourself up for false negatives in the future.

Comment: Thank you, but the code im working with is quite huge, I can't even possibly think how I can display it here properly :$

Comment: is there anything that you know of that I should be looking for ?

Comment: *(it will only ever work the first time you use it)*.  That is not strictly true.

Comment: @Kam: One crude option is to start simplifying your code into successively smaller and smaller test-cases (see e.g. http://sscce.org).